# How can i lag a ts object in R?

Tags: r, time-series, lag

I have a dataframe with 436 observation per year for every variable.

I made each variable a ts object through the command

```
ts("a", frequency=436)
```

Now, I would like to shift a variable ahead of 1 year (for example, from 2010 to 2011)

Therefore, i tried with the command

```
lag("a", k=1)
```

But it gives me:

> Error: `x` must be a vector, not a ts object, do you want `stats::lag()`?

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Transferred my comment to an answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely have dplyr installed.  It clobbers R's `lag` with its own incompatible `lag`.  You can do one of these:

1. As the message says use `stats::lag` instead of `lag` to force the use of R's `lag`.
2. Define `lag <- stats::lag` and then use `lag` as usual.  To refer to dplyr's lag you can use `dplyr::lag`.
3. Do not load dplyr.
4. Load dplyr but do it like this: `library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))`.  If you do that `lag` will refer to R's `lag` and `dplyr::lag` will refer to dplyr's incompatible `lag`.
5. Use `flag` from the collapse package if your data is a numeric ts series -- the one in the question won't work with this alternative since it is a character ts series.